# How to get the alpha of an UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

I have a UIImage. I need to find out its alpha value. Can someone explain it to me in detail, providing links to any references and also source code of how to go about this. Please don't provide answers for finding out the alpha of the UIImageView because I do NOT need that. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you *exactly* mean by UIImage alpha ?

Comment: `imageView.alpha` will give you alpha

Comment: You have to obtain a *CGImageRef*. Once you have it you can use the method *CGImageGetAlphaInfo* that return the information of the alpha channel of the image.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya he said not to use UIImageView. UIImage has not the property alpha

Comment: hi i am also facing the same see once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686489/how-to-get-the-alpha-channel-alone-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

You have to obtain a *CGImageRef*. Once you have it you can use the method *CGImageGetAlphaInfo* that return the information of the alpha channel of the image.